# tcp handshake terminated by FIN /JSON data not retrieved

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, tcp

Hi
 I have a website html embadded with java script, the website uploaded into apache tomcat, the website suppose to contact another server and retrieve json data back, this is not happening the  packet tracing shows the tcp handshake is terminated by a FIN state the packet send before the FIN state has a checksum incorrect, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this ? do you think the checksum incorrect is terminating the handshake ? and hwo to avoide that ? the following is my ajax jquery code 
note: both apache server and the other server are in the same domain.
Thank in advance 
LS

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
var home_add='http://myhome.net:3300/gateway';
$('#handshake').click(function(){
     alert(" sending json data");
                      $.ajax({                 /* start ajax function to send data */ 
                          url:home_add,
                          type:'POST',
                          datatype:'json',
                          contanttype:'text/json',
                          async: false, 
                          error:function(){ alert("handshake didn't go through")}, /* call disconnect function */
                          data:{
                          "supportedConnectionTypes": "long-polling",
                          "channel": "/meta/handshake",
                          "version": "1:0"
                          },
                          success:function(data){
                          $("p").append(data+"<br/>");
                           alert("sucessful handshake")
                           }                    
                          })   

                          })
})
```

Comment: `contanttype` is misspelled, but it would have nothing to do with the content type of the response if included: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding the [same-origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy). The same-origin policy used by XMLHttpRequest, the basis for jQuery's AJAX functionality, is:

- The two hostnames must be exactly the same (not just part of a higher level domain).
  **Example:** A web page from `careers.stackoverflow.com` can access the same domain but not `beta.careers.stackoverflow.com`, `stackoverflow.com`, or `foo.stackoverflow.com`.
- The two protocols must be exactly the same (http/https).
  **Example:** A web page from `http://stackoverflow.com` cannot access `https://stackoverflow.com` and vice-versa.
- The two port numbers must be exactly the same (except in Internet Explorer).
  **Example:** A web page from `http://stackoverflow.com` cannot access `http://stackoverflow.com:8080` and vice-versa in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, or Opera.

You will have to do one of these:

- Use the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) HTTP header in AJAX responses, with the obvious disadvantage of excluding browsers such as IE and older versions of the others that do not support it
- Use [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/), which [is supported by jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) though not for synchronous requests (which you should avoid anyway because they can hang the browser)
- Proxy HTTP requests from the server your web page is served on to the other server

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply but if this is the problem do you think it is detected as early as a tcp handshake setup, which basically passively opening a port for connection then sending SYN and ACK between the client and the server but in my case the handshake will be terminated here with FIN state. your feedback is appreciated Thanks :)